# Netflix Suro key features

Tags: message-queue, apache-kafka, suro

I'm trying to wrap my head around [Netflix Suro](https://github.com/Netflix/suro), but there isn't much information about it in the net.

What are the key features of the product and how is it different from Apache Kafka or RabbitMQ?

For me it looks exactly like many others queue servers with some pre-built connectors to 3rd party storages/queues. I think I may really missing a point here. Maybe it's a perfect instrument for cloud based infrastructure or offers no-brain integration with other Netflix infrastructure when others cannot. 
Can somebody shed some light on this piece of technology?

Answer (score 2):

Recently Netflix has archived this project, judging by their [last commit](https://github.com/Netflix/suro/commit/e73d1a2e5b0492e41feb5a57d9e2a2e741a38453).

It seems that they have replaced it completely with Kafka in their [data pipeline stack](http://techblog.netflix.com/2016/02/evolution-of-netflix-data-pipeline.html).

Answer (score 0):

Not much difference, just a business decision I guess

some pointers:
https://github.com/Netflix/suro/wiki/FAQ

Comment: this rational why Netflix use Suro and that's totally clear. But what I don't understand is when should I use Suro when I start a greenfield project. What are the strongest sides of it and where it's not so good.